# PostBackUrl and javascript submit form

Tags: javascript, submit, postbackurl

I have little strange situation. 
I want to submit form with java script on click with submit button or with form1.submit(); it is the same.

```
 <form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server" class="form-horizontal" action="frmSomeOtherPage.aspx" method="post">
 <input id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
```

In order the folowing code to work fine:

form1.btnSubmit.click();

I must have on the page following line: (?!??!)

```
<asp:LinkButton ID='btnSubmitForm' runat='server' CssClass='btn-link' PostBackUrl='~/frmSomeOtherPage.aspx'></asp:LinkButton>
```

The interesting thing is that i didnt use anywhere btnSubmitForm!
If the line with LinkButton was not there the form frmSomeOtherPage return error:
Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.............

If it is there LinkButton everything is just fine, although is nowhere used.
I know that if I put <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %> on frmSomeOtherPage  everything will work.... But that is not solution...
Just existence on the unused LinkButton solves problem but it is a little bit strange... even if we put PostBackUrl='~/frmNonExistingPage.aspx' on LinkButton still works correctly. And the LinkButton could be hidden also, still works well.

Any Idea?

Comment: What is the question?